# Retrieve token data from Kubernetes Service Account in Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I'm creating a Kubernetes Service Account using terraform and trying to output the token from the Kubernetes Secret that it creates.

```
resource "kubernetes_service_account" "ci" {
  metadata {
    name = "ci"
  }
}

data "kubernetes_secret" "ci" {
  metadata {
    name = "${kubernetes_service_account.ci.default_secret_name}"
  }
}

output "ci_token" {
  value = "${data.kubernetes_secret.ci.data.token}"
}
```

According to [the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/data-sources.html#data-source-lifecycle) this should make the data block defer getting its values until the 'apply' phase because of the computed value of `default_secret_name`, but when I run `terraform apply` it gives me this error:

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

* output.ci_token: Resource 'data.kubernetes_secret.ci' does not have attribute 'data.token' for variable 'data.kubernetes_secret.ci.data.token'
```

Adding `depends_on` to the `kubernetes_secret` data block doesn't make any difference.

If I comment out the `output` block, it creates the resources fine, then I can uncomment it, apply again, and everything acts normally, since the Kubernetes Secret exists already.

I've also made a Github issue [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/436).

**Update**

The accepted answer does solve this problem, but I omitted another output to simplify the question, which doesn't work with this solution:

```
output "ci_crt" {
  value = "${data.kubernetes_secret.ci.data.ca.crt}"
}
```

```
* output.ci_ca: lookup: lookup failed to find 'ca.crt' in:

${lookup(data.kubernetes_secret.ci.data, "ca.crt")}
```

This particular issue is [reported here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/334) due to [a bug in Terraform](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10876), which is fixed in version 0.12.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This works:

```
resource "kubernetes_service_account" "ci" {
  metadata {
    name = "ci"
  }
}

data "kubernetes_secret" "ci" {
  metadata {
    name = kubernetes_service_account.ci.default_secret_name
  }
}

output "ci_token" {
  sensitive = true
  value = lookup(data.kubernetes_secret.ci.data, "token")
}
```

Comment: default_secret_name was deprecated in 2022