# Failed to retrieve sa token using terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I need to retrieve SA token using output in my pipeline, i found an solution in here

[Retrieve token data from Kubernetes Service Account in Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56080359/retrieve-token-data-from-kubernetes-service-account-in-terraform)

but still dont work and get this error:

```
│ Error: Invalid function argument
│ 
│   on access.tf line 51, in output "deploy_user_token":
│   51:   value = lookup(data.kubernetes_secret.deploy_user_secret.data, "token")
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.kubernetes_secret.deploy_user_secret.data has a sensitive value
│ 
│ Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: argument must not be null.
```

My code:

```
resource "kubernetes_service_account" "deploy_user" {
  depends_on = [kubernetes_namespace.namespace]
  metadata {
    name      = "deploy-user"
    namespace = var.namespace
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_role" "deploy_user_full_access" {
  metadata {
    name      = "deploy-user-full-access"
    namespace = var.namespace
  }

  rule {
    api_groups = ["", "extensions", "apps", "networking.istio.io"]
    resources  = ["*"]
    verbs      = ["*"]
  }
  rule {
    api_groups = ["batch"]
    resources  = ["jobs", "cronjobs"]
    verbs      = ["*"]
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_role_binding" "deploy_user_view" {
  metadata {
    name      = "deploy-user-view"
    namespace = var.namespace
  }
  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "Role"
    name      = kubernetes_role.deploy_user_full_access.metadata.0.name
  }
  subject {
    kind      = "ServiceAccount"
    name      = kubernetes_service_account.deploy_user.metadata.0.name
    namespace = var.namespace
  }
}

data "kubernetes_secret" "deploy_user_secret" {
  metadata {
    name = kubernetes_service_account.deploy_user.default_secret_name
  }
}

output "deploy_user_token" {
  value = lookup(data.kubernetes_secret.deploy_user_secret.data, "token")
}
```

someone have an idea that what i do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that you missing the namespace declaration on your data object, you need it to look like that:

```
data "kubernetes_secret" "deploy_user_secret" {
  metadata {
    name = kubernetes_service_account.deploy_user.default_secret_name
    namespace = var.namespace
  }
}
```

you also need the set `sensitive = true` on your output:

```
output "deploy_user_token" {
  sensitive = true
  value = lookup(data.kubernetes_secret.deploy_user_secret.data, "token")
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mendi, its works!! i really forgot namespace in data.

But the output show with "sensitive" flag, istead of show real value, like this:

Outputs:
deploy_user_token = <sensitive>

do you know what can be?

thanks!

Comment: you always can use the nonsensitive function, in your case it need to be like that:

`output "deploy_user_token" {
  value = lookup(nonsensitive(data.kubernetes_secret.deploy_user_secret.data), "token")
}`